# Visual Studio updates binaries of project which is not supposed to be built

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

I'm trying to prevent `Visual Studio` from overriding my binary folder of a project which is not supposed to be used during a build. Imaging the following solution structure:

`App1 -> LibB -> LibA`

Every time I'm trying to build the `LibB` project (build/rebuild) it replaces `LibA.dll` in my `App1` binary folder. The real issue is in different version of `LibA.dll` used by `App1` and `LibB`. Imaging I have another `App2` project:

`App1 -> LibB (v2) -> LibA (v2)
App2 -> LibB (v2) -> LibA (v2)
LibB (v2) -> LibA (v1)`

And now every time I'm building the `App1` project it ruins the binary folder of my `App2` project because when the `LibB` project is build it moves `LibA.dll (v1)` to my `App2` binary folder which is not expected behavior.

ps#1: I cannot update `LibB (v2)` to use `LibA (v2)` just because it's a simplified issue description and there are plenty of dependencies like I described above. Let's say it's going to be my long term solution.

ps#2: If you try to build `LibB` project it WILL update `App1` and `App2` binary folders with `LibA.dll (v1)` and ruin both app projects.

ps#3: I recreated a test solution with similar dependencies model and it works just fine so it's an issue of the existing solution I'm trying to fix.

How can I prevent `Visual Studio` from updating a parent project when a child project is being built?

Comment: Some random points: If you look in the Build Configuration Manager is everything the same Platform like x86 or Any CPU.   Besides the normal project dependencies could one of your projects explicitly be refrencing an old LibA (v1) and copying it in explicitly such as "Include in project" and you really wanted the reference to come in via the project dependency.  If you search for the lib name as a string in the actual project and solution file you may see an odball "forced" reference or even a "Linked" reference.  I have seen this with Winforms that were really in two projects at once.

Answer (score 1):

When using project references in Visual Studio it is the design of Visual Studio to keep them in sync, this is by design. If you have shared libs across multiple applications you should have them in different solutions and manage the dependencies across solutions with a package management product like nuget.

Comment: But why I'm unable to reproduce it in my test solution. I recreated a test solution with similar dependencies model and it works just fine so it's an issue of the existing solution I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent Visual Studio from updating a parent project when a child project is being built?
>
> every time I'm building the App1 project it ruins the binary folder of my App2 project because when the LibB project is build it moves LibA.dll (v1) to my App2 binary folder which is not expected behavior.

I believe it is by-design, never the less one way to stop App1 ruining the Bin Folder of your App2 project is to make copies of the Project Files (.csproj's) and change the Output Bin folder in the Project Properties.

Then have a few different Solution Files (.sln's) to open the different version reference configured projects.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same issue using a brand new solution and projects - wasn't able to do that. Everything works as expected. In my current solution most likely I've got some weird project dependency issue when the App2 replace binaries in the folder of the App1 project when it's not supposed to.

Comment: Sounds like a Solution got corrupted/confused. Delete the .suo file, clean solution or better yet just use the new .sln without the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your dependencies across projects sorted and your *Configuration Manager* settings are proper for a solution-level build

You can always build a specific project individually from within the solution as well

Answer (score 0):

Don't use *project references*, instead link to compiled binaries of libraries from some external folder like *C:\DeployedBinaries* and whenever required copy desired binaries to *C:\DeployedBinaries* manually.